# Excel - VBA: Auto Print multiple File Only 1sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, printing

i have a code to Auto print multiple File but this code print every sheet in File

now i have 44 file in every File is 3 Sheet [Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3] i want to print only Sheet1

```
 Sub auto_print()
'

'

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

Dim varFile As Variant
Dim inFile As Integer
Dim OPENFILE
Dim currFile
Dim N
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo 100
'
currFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
varFile = _
Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel file, *.xls", MultiSelect:=True)
If (IsArray(varFile)) Then
For intfile = 1 To UBound(varFile)
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=varFile(intfile)
OPENFILE = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'
For N = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
Sheets(N).Activate
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
Next N
Workbooks(OPENFILE).Close
Next intfile
Else
MsgBox "You did not select any file.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
End If

100 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
For N = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
Sheets(N).Activate
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
Next N
```

To

```
Sheets("Sheet1").PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
```